# Как сделать, чтобы editable div выглядел так же как textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, style

Есть некая CMS. К сайту на этой CMS применена некая тема оформления. Есть страница на этом сайте. Внешний вид отдельно взятого элемента на странице определяется кучей правил из кучи CSS-файлов темы.

На странице находится div, у которого выставлен атрибут `contenteditable="true"`. Хочется сделать так, чтобы он выглядел как textarea.
Можно конечно посмотреть какие стили применены к textarea и написать свой css который будет применяться на этот div. Но при переходе на другую тему, или может быть даже при редактировании текущей темы, придется этот css переделывать. Хотелось бы какое-нибудь удобное решение, чтобы один раз написал и оно всегда работало.

В качестве возможной альтернативы можно было бы использовать свойство CSS [appearance](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp), но оно к сожалению removed и уже не поддерживается половиной браузеров. Хочется универсальное решение, которое работает на всех браузерах, чтобы не пришлось под каждый браузер писать свой код.

В общем подскажите, как можно решить такую задачу? Может это можно сделать через javascript?

В комментариях просят добавить пример кода. Добавляю:

Тема оформления 1:

```
textarea {border-style: dotted;}
```

Тема оформления 2:

```
textarea {border: 3px solid; border-color: green;}
```

Тема оформления 3:

```
textarea {border: 1px solid; border-radius: 5px;}
```

И так далее - темы могут быть какие угодно.
Собственно HTML:

```
<textarea>Text text text.</textarea>
<div id="user_input" class="editalbe_div">Text text text.</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы на любой из тем оформления данный div выглядел так же как и textarea.

Comment: напишите Ваш код в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что идеальной схожести во всех браузерах будет не добиться.  Таким образом, как вариант: (без *appearance*)

```css
* {
    font-family: arial;
}

.textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 2px;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}


textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='textarea' contentEditable>текст текст текст</div>

<br/><br/>

<textarea>текст текст текст</textarea>
```

Выглядит похоже, но конечно не копия.

Для наглядности всё же продемонстрирую пример с использованием *appearance*

```css
* {
    font-family: arial;
}

.textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
}


textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='textarea' contentEditable>текст текст текст</div>

<br/><br/>

<textarea>текст текст текст</textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

При таком решении как раз есть проблема - если я переключусь на тему, в которой textarea имеет толстый край с закругленными краями, мне придется переписывать CSS для класса textarea. А хотелось бы как раз универсальное решение - чтобы один раз написал и оно всегда работало. Например, чтобы класс textarea генерировался автоматически, исходя из того, как выглядит элемент textarea в данной теме.

Comment: генерировать html + css не умеет , генератор html это php - а вы как хотите генерировать ваш  .textarea?